Помогите мне сжать код python
Кажется, у меня получился довольно большой код. и я хочу его уменьшить:
if result_ >= 1000 and result_ <= 1999:
    print("bronze1")
else:
        if result_ >= 2000 and result_ <= 2999:
            print("bronze2")
        else:
                if result_ >= 3000 and result_ <= 3999:
                    print("bronze3")
                else:
                    if result_ >= 4000 and result_ <= 4999:
                        print("silver1")
                    else:
                        if result_ >= 5000 and result_ <= 5999:
                            print("silver2")
                        else:
                            if result_ >= 6000 and result_ <= 6999:
                                print("silver3")
                            else:
                                if result_ >= 7000 and result_ <= 7999:
                                    print("gold1")
                                else:
                                    if result_ >= 8000 and result_ <= 8999:
                                        print("gold2")
                                    else:
                                        if result_ >= 9000 and result_ <= 9999:
                                            print("gold3")
                                        else:
                                            if result_ >= 10000 and result_ <= 10999:
                                                print("diamond1")
                                            else:
                                                if result_ >= 11000 and result_ <= 11999:
                                                    print("diamond2")
                                                else:
                                                    if result_ >= 12000 and result_ <= 12999:
                                                        print("diamond3")
                                                    else:
                                                         if result_ >= 13000 and result_ <= 13999:
                                                             print("mythic1")
                                                         else:
                                                             if result_ >= 14000 and result_ <= 14999:
                                                                 print("mythic2")
                                                             else:
                                                                  if result_ >= 15000 and result_ <= 15999:
                                                                      print("mythic3")
                                                                  else:
                                                                       if result_ >= 16000 and result_ <= 16999:
                                                                           print("legendary1")
                                                                       else:
                                                                           if result_ >= 17000 and result_ <= 17999:
                                                                               print("legendary2")
                                                                           else:
                                                                               if result_ >= 18000 and result_ <= 18999:
                                                                                   print("legendary3")
                                                                               else:
                                                                                   if result_ >= 19000:
                                                                                       print("master")


Ну как минимум странно, что вы не в курсе про существование elif

table = (
    ( 1000, "bronze1"   ), ( 2000, "bronze2"   ), ( 3000, "bronze3"   ),
    ( 4000, "silver1"   ), ( 5000, "silver2"   ), ( 6000, "silver3"   ),
    ( 7000, "gold1"     ), ( 8000, "gold2"     ), ( 9000, "gold3"     ),
    (10000, "diamond1"  ), (11000, "diamond2"  ), (12000, "diamond3"  ),
    (13000, "mythic1"   ), (14000, "mythic2"   ), (15000, "mythic3"   ),
    (16000, "legendary1"), (17000, "legendary2"), (18000, "legendary3"),
    (19000, "master"    )
)
for value, grade in reversed(table):
    if result_ >= value:
        print(grade)
        break


Для случая равномерного шага решение может быть довольно простым:
treasures = ["", "bronze1", "bronze2", "bronze3", "silver1" и т.д....]
print(treasures[min(19, result//1000)])


Для данного конкретного примера красиво, но если вдруг в будущем приспичит добавить что-то вроде 100, 250 или 500, то будет ой

@andreymal Ну да, это уже по обстоятельствам надо смотреть

Как ещё один вариант:
import bisect

my_elo = 18943

grades = {
    1000 : "bronze1", 
    2000 : "bronze2", 
    3000 : "bronze3",
    4000 : "silver1", 
    5000 : "silver2", 
    6000 : "silver3",
    7000 : "gold1", 
    8000 : "gold2", 
    9000 : "gold3",
    10000 : "diamond1", 
    11000 : "diamond2", 
    12000 : "diamond3",
    13000 : "mythic1", 
    14000 : "mythic2", 
    15000 : "mythic3",
    16000 : "legendary1", 
    17000 : "legendary2", 
    18000 : "legendary3",
    19000 : "master"
}

rank_elo, rank = zip(*grades.items())
index = bisect.bisect_right(rank_elo, my_elo) - 1
if index >= 0:
    print(rank[index])
else:
    print("У вас нету ранга!")

Вывод:
legendary3

[Program finished]

